# MySQL "Advanced Where" Query

Tags: mysql, sql, advanced-search

I would like to know is there any possible way, whereby MySQL query can dynamically search whatever is there in the `WHERE` clause.

For example if the query is

```
Select * 
from table 
where item = 'Dell Optiplex 390'
```

It should search for rows having:

```
Dell Optiplex 390

Dell Desktop Optiplex 390

Dell Laptop Optiplex 390

Optiplex dual core 390

etc., etc.
```

Comment: read about `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

Comment: Do you need all words to appear in the result? your last result "Optiplex dual core 390" does not fit to the requirement.

Comment: i want if it match even one word then that row should be consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these sort of search capabilities I think you are looking for a matching algorithm. You can use the [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), there is a php function [`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) that implement this algorithm if you are using php, to get the matching data and there is also [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), and if your data is in English only and one word column you can use [Soundex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

This is a start, you will find a lot of implementations out there for these algorithms in Mysql.

Comment: "there is a php function that implement this algorithm" - can you provide a link ?

Comment: It is [`int levenshtein ( string $str1 , string $str2 )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: thank you so much to provide this php function and it would be helpful too, but anything in MySQL?

Comment: @RamuPL, As I said there are a lot of implementations for this algorithm in mysql. Try to google it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know that field consist any of you words.

```
Select *  
from table  
where item like '%Dell%' OR item like '%Optiplex%' or item like '%390%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a good answer here which was deleted, I would modify that answer to:

```
Select * from table where 
lower(item) like '%dell%optiplex%390%' or
lower(item) like '%optiplex%390%' or
lower(item) like '%dell%laptop%390%' or ...
```

Comment: this is in case he wishes all words to appear in the result!

Comment: @Michael of course, you can add many 'likes' to the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL `LIKE` clause with wild cards:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE item LIKE '%Dell%Optiplex390%';
```

Here's a good reference guide:

- [MySQL Wildcard Filtering using LIKE](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Wildcard_Filtering_using_LIKE).

Comment: @alfasin, I probably did not see your reply before posting.